# Multiple Vlookup Result

Tags: excel, vba

[image][image]i am trying to get multiple vlookup in single cell

I am getting **#VALUE!** error with the below function, Need help to correct the code

```
MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
Dim i As Long
Dim Result As String
For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
  If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
    For J = 1 To i - 1
    If LookupRange.Cells(J, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
      If LookupRange.Cells(J, ColumnNumber) = LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) Then
        GoTo Skip
      End If
    End If
    Next J
    Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
Skip:
  End If
Next i
MultipleLookupNoRept = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Your code is great, you forgot one little thing, to return a `String` from your `Function`. Modify the first line to `Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer) As String` and it will work for you

Comment: Thanks But again i am getting the same error

Comment: how are you using it ? you are entering the correct parameters from an Excel sheet?

Comment: yes i am using correct parameter (Screen Shot Attached)

Comment: remove the last parameter `0` from your cell, you don't have it in your created `Function`, try only with `=MultipleLookupNoRept(H5,E5:F7,2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please add the function with 0

Comment: what does it suppose to do ?

Comment: If the lookup is not in range it will put 0

Comment: just use `=IFERROR(MultipleLookupNoRept(E7,E3:F5,2),0)` instead of modifying the code

Comment: No its notworking

Comment: it worked for me. did you modify the ranges in my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. Most of it is the original code.

```
Function MultipleLookupNoRept(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Result As String

    For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
      If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
        Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
      End If
    Next i
    If (Len(Result) = 0) Then
        MultipleLookupNoRept = 0
        Else
        MultipleLookupNoRept = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Need one more changes in this code. If the result is in Duplicate its considering only one(See my attached screenshot)

Comment: if possible please help me on the below my Question              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41442487/update-the-data-in-new-sheet-based-on-date-ranges

Answer (score 0):

```
'This code should help 
' Syntax =MVLOOKUP(Lookup_value,Table_array,Col_index_number)
Option Explicit
Function mvlookup(lookupValue, tableArray As Range, colIndexNum As Long, _
Optional NotUsed As Variant) As Variant

Dim initTable As Range
Dim myRowMatch As Variant
Dim myRes() As Variant
Dim myStr As String
Dim initTableCols As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ubound_myRes As Long

Set initTable = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set initTable = Intersect(tableArray, _
tableArray.Parent.UsedRange.EntireRow)
On Error GoTo 0

If initTable Is Nothing Then
mvlookup = CVErr(xlErrRef)
Exit Function
End If

initTableCols = initTable.Columns.Count

i = 0
Do
myRowMatch = Application.Match(lookupValue, initTable.Columns(1), 0)

If IsError(myRowMatch) Then
Exit Do
Else
i = i + 1
ReDim Preserve myRes(1 To i)
myRes(i) _
= initTable(1).Offset(myRowMatch - 1, colIndexNum - 1).Text
If initTable.Rows.Count <= myRowMatch Then
Exit Do
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set initTable = initTable.Offset(myRowMatch, 0) _
.Resize(initTable.Rows.Count - myRowMatch, _
initTableCols)
On Error GoTo 0
If initTable Is Nothing Then
Exit Do
End If
End If
Loop

If i = 0 Then
mvlookup = CVErr(xlErrNA)
Exit Function
End If

myStr = ""
For i = LBound(myRes) To UBound(myRes)
myStr = myStr & ", " & myRes(i)
Next i

mvlookup = Mid(myStr, 3)

End Function
```