# Excel - Show all results with multiple results vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

In my Excel file there are different columns. One of them shows all the names. In my tool it's possible to look up the data by name. The problem is that some names appear more than once in the column. How can I show all the results in stead of only the first name founded?

Comment: Show them.. how? concatenated?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, not really sure what you're asking here, maybe some screenshots would help.

Comment: You could try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438108/multiple-vlookup-result

Comment: I can look up the data from for example "Jack". But if there are 4 Jack's in the column, you will not know because it only shows the 1st Jack. So I want it to show (in a userform or something else) all "Jacks" so you can select the right "Jack".

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` only returns one value. If you need multiple values, then you would need to write a excel macro

Naz